# How can I use xargs replace but keep space delimiter?

Tags: xargs

Consider the following `xargs` usage:

```
echo Alice Bob Carol | xargs -n1 echo
```

It produces three echo statements like this

```
echo Alice 
echo Bob 
echo Carol
```

Consider this modified `xargs` usage:

```
echo Alice Bob Carol | xargs -n1 -I% echo Hello, %. How are you?
```

It produces one echo statement instead of the desired three:

```
echo Hello, Alice Bob Carol. How are you?
```

This is because `-I` changes the way the input stream is delimited, as per the man page:

> unquoted blanks do not terminate input items; instead the separator is the newline character

**Is it possible to keep the space delimiter when using the replace technique?**

The best I've come up with is to use `-d` to specify the space delimiter, is there a better way?

```
echo -n Alice Bob Carol | xargs -n1 -I% -d\  echo Hello, %. How are you?
```

Comment: The only other way to achieve the same results using only `xargs` is by piping it twice: `echo Alice Bob Carol | xargs -n1 echo | xargs -n1 -I% echo Hello, %. How are you? `, but using `-d\ ` is way shorter and more efficient.